# xcode searchBar over google map not working

Tags: xcode, google-maps, swift3, searchbar

I've a view containing a mapView (google maps) and some other controllers.
One is the searchBar. The problem is that if I put the search bar over the map (using addSubView), when I try to click inside the search bar, nothing appens... I'm new to xcode and swift and I can't figure out which is the problem.

[This is the hierarchy of the controllers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQm5J.jpg)

Then, in viewDidLoad I did "mapView.addSubView(searchBar), ..."

[As result I can see the searchBar but if I click inside, it doesn't work (is not responding and I can't write anything to search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcSjK.jpg)

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var advSearchButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var logoIcon: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var trafficButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var satelliteButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var zoomInButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var zoomOutButton: UIButton!
```

here is what I do in viewDidLoad:

```
mapView.addSubview(zoomInButton)
mapView.addSubview(zoomOutButton)
mapView.addSubview(trafficButton)
mapView.addSubview(satelliteButton)
mapView.addSubview(searchBar)
mapView.addSubview(advSearchButton)
mapView.addSubview(logoIcon)
mapView.moveCamera(GMSCameraUpdate.setCamera(camera))
```

As I said before, the searchbar is correctly visible, but I can't write anything inside it...

Comment: Images doesn't grab attention, please the code you tried here.

Answer (score 1):

The search bar is not working because it is not able to detect touches as the gesture Recognizers of GMSMapView are not letting searchbar to become the first responder.

So one solution is to remove the gestureRecognisers of gmsmapView and then the search bar will start detecting touches.

add this line `mapView.gestureRecognizers?.removeAll()` and the search bar will detect taps over it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you put search bar inside map view? Mine it into the same level as map view. The other elements too. It is possible to use constraints to locate the views as you with without such parent-child dependencies.

Comment: Xcode put them automatically there when I move them in the storyboard...

Comment: Anyway the buttons are working perfectly... the only problem is the search bar and I can't understand the problem. I did the same with both buttons and searchbar

Comment: so , try `mapView.superview.addSubview(searchBar)`

Comment: this way it doesn't show me the searchBar (and xcode tells me to add ? after superview)